# Find annotation from PDFAnnotation at point

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a few annotations onto my view. What I am trying to do now is find these annotations with CGPoint from my touch location. This is what I got so far:

```
func annotationWithHitTest(at: CGPoint) -> PDFAnnotation? {
    for annotation in annotations {
        return annotation
    }
    return nil
}
```

So in my loop of all my annotations, I am trying to find the one that is closest to my CGPoint. How would I accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

I am able to get the CGPoint of the annotation, however it will mostly not match the CGPoint of my touch location, so would I get it so it finds the closet item?

```
func annotationWithHitTest(at: CGPoint) -> PDFAnnotation? {
        for annotation in annotations {

            print("Touch")

            print(at)

            print("Annotation")

            print(annotation.bounds.origin)

            return annotation
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming annotation is a UIView?

Comment: Pretty much yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-- Updated -- Realized this is for a PDFAnnotation, not a UIView.

You can find the point selected with the PDFAnnotation API..

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfpage/1504793-annotation

Comment: Annotations do not have frame, they have bounds.

Comment: I tried with the bounds.contains but that did not work

Comment: That is because PDFAnnotation is not a UIView (: See updated answer